# How to sort an array based on enum hash and return the maximum in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, enums, enumerable

```
enum custom: {
   AB1:  1,
   AB45: 10,
   XY:   15
}
```

Input:

```
array = [AB45, XY]
```

Output should be: XY, as XY(key)'s value is maximum(15)

I tried the following:
`MyClassName.customs.values_at(*array)` . This returns [10,15]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Output should be: XY. Updated the question as well.

Comment: Can you use `max_by`? `MyClassName.customs.max_by { |_, value| value }.first`

Comment: I hope you are aware that Ruby on Rails 3 had its end-of-life 3 years ago and contains known, unfixed security holes.

Comment: `array = [AB45, XY]` – What is `AB45`, what is `XY`? Are those constants? Or is that a type and you actually have `array = [:AB45, :XY]`?

Comment: @Stefan Both in the array I can design it as constants or string or symbol. I prefer to have it as strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When you construct the array, the two constants `AB45` and `XY` are dereferenced, and the array contains the referenced objects. There is no way to get the name of the constant from the value.

Comment: Any other way I can achieve this. It need not be using enum. My requirement is, 
there will be a list or array of items with hierarchy attached to it. 
When an array of items is given, sort and get the highest.

Comment: It is not possible. There is no link from the array values to the constant names.

Comment: @sofs1 : Your Hash contains symbols as keys. Can you set the array as `array = [:AB45, :XY]` ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Do you know by chance, where I can learn about the `enum` method used here? I don't find it in the Ruby Docs. As for the OP's question, I wonder whether it is somehow possible to use the `object_id` of the constants in the array, to unambiguously identify them with "their" identity in the enum, i.e. that we locate them by identity instead of equality.

Comment: @user1934428 - Yes. Also, I not completely clear with symbols in Ruby. I can change my enum hash key as string as well.

Comment: A symbol is unique, so you can really look up by symbol instead of by value, but since I do not know the `enum` method (as I indicated in my comment to JörgWMittag), I can't give a concrete implementation suggestion.

Comment: @user1934428: "I wonder whether it is somehow possible to use the `object_id` of the constants in the array" – Constants aren't objects, therefore they don't have an `object_id`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : OK, see the problem. Constant's **values** have object id. But I see if the constans are bound to an `Integer`, this does not help. With a String, we could do a `MYCONST = 'foo'.dup`, and `MYCONST.object_id` would be different from the object id of `YOURCONST = 'foo'.dup`, but integers don't get a new object id when dup'ed. Maybe the original design of the data structure (based on integers) was poorly choosen?

Comment: @user1934428: The problem is that the OP expects to go from a value to a constant name. That is just not possible. Objects don't "know" the variables they are assigned to. They might not even be assigned to variables anyway. Or they might be assigned to multiple variables. If the elements of the array were, for example, strings with the names, then there would be no problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag . I'm fine redesigning my input array as strings and enum hash as string => int .